# How to use Auctex + preview-latex + orgmode in emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I use Emacs orgmode exclusively. I installed auctex from Melpa. My understanding is that `preview-latex` is packaged with auctex with no special setup required.

1. I can't seem to summon `preview-latex` on any inline latex equations
2. It seems like I have to change from orgmode to latex-mode to get the "latex" option in the toolbar.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [best method](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) I found to preview latex in orgmode is:

1. `sudo apt-get install dvipng`
2. Restart emacs
3. Place point at the beg of a latex inline equation in one of my .org files
4. `C-c C-x C-l`

Equation goes from this:

```
$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a \cdot c}{b \cdot d} = \frac{product\ of\ numerators}{product\ of\ denominators}$$
```

To this:
[image]

Use `C-c C-x C-l` to revert.

I do have Auctex installed (though I don't think `dvipng` uses it at all. And in my emacs `init` file I have:

```
* AucTex: Require AucTex
(require 'tex-site') 

* LaTeX: Enable LaTeX Math mode by default
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
```

This is very sweet!

Comment: That tutorial is still valid as far as it goes, but there have been some additions to org that it does not cover (I'm pretty sure I wrote it !-) In particular, for recent versions of orgmode, you should check the value of the variable `org-preview-latex-process-alist` to see the available processing options. In addition to `dvipng` and `imagemagick`, there is now `dvisvgm` which creates SVG images. And there is a plugin mechanism so that other options (who knows? maybe even `preview-latex`) can be accommodated in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything wrong: `org-mode` has its own latex preview mechanism and does not use (indeed, cannot use) `preview-latex`. There was talk a long time ago on the ML about integrating `preview-latex` into `org-mode`, but it has never been done.

Comment: Aha! Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

make sure dvipng dvisvgm installed correctly

`(executable-find "dvipng")`
`(executable-find "dvisvgm")`

then add

`(setq org-latex-compiler "xelatex")`

to your init.el
to make default latex compiler as xelatex